# What should I prefer, setting it in class path or in dependencies

Tags: jakarta-ee

My ABC.jar in the .ear want to access the XYZ.jar in the lib directory of the .ear.
What should I prefer, setting it in class path or dependencies. Whatever you suggestion is please also let me know how to do it.

```
Here is the structure of the .ear:
ABC.jar - contains EJB.
XYZ.jar - also contains EJBs 

.ear
 |____ ABC.jar
 |
 |____ ABCClient.jar
 |
 |____ web.war
 |
 |____ /lib
         |
         | ____ XYZ.jar
         |
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not move `XYZ.jar` to the same level as `ABC.jar`, and add it to the classpath of the jars that require it, by adding it to the `META-INF\MANIFEST.MF`'s `class-path` value?

Comment: No I don't want to disturb the structure. I am sure there is a way so work with this structure.